# Use onOptionsItemSelected with a button in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-button

I trying to personalize the Android tutorial about Layout Changes (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html), but in the code there is this code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
        // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html
        // for more.
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;

    case R.id.action_add_item:
        // Hide the "empty" view since there is now at least one item in the
        // list.
        findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addItem();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In my case I don't have a button in the menu, but I woud use an external button. I trying to use this button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextComment"
            android:text="Post"
            android:onClick="add" />
```

With the method

```
    public void add(View view) {
    findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    addItem();

}
```

But this solution doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onOptionsItemSelected` is for an options `menu` used with `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. Simply move this code to your `onClick` if you want it to work for the `Button`s and `switch` on the `Button` `id`.

```
public void add(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.buttonPost:
        findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addItem();
        break;
    case R.id.another_button_id:
        // do something else
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I trying your answere but I have this exception:

...

06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328):  at com.tmp.NewsDetailActivity.add(NewsDetailActivity.java:186)
06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328):  ... 14 more

The row 186 is findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);

where is android.R.id.empty?

Comment: You don't have a `View` in your `layout` with that `id` that you inflate with `setContentView(...)`. You will need to add whatever that is suppose to be (`Button`, `EditText`, etc...) to your xml

Comment: ok i solved removing the row because i erased the element in the layout

Answer (score 0):

Put an `OnClickListener` on your button instead:

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonPost).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: I trying your answere but I have this exception: ... 06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328): at com.tmp.NewsDetailActivity.add(NewsDetailActivity.java:186) 06-28 17:26:06.521: E/AndroidRuntime(17328): ... 14 more The row 186 is findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE); where is android.R.id.empty?

Comment: Does your layout have a view with that ID?